# How to foreach and display 2 diffent type in array in same row ?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array include name of the home team and away team . But i don't know how to display it in the same row . My array like this :

```
[8] => Array
    (
        [comm_match_team] => localteam
        [player_name] => Fraizer Campbell
    )
[9] => Array
    (
        [comm_match_team] => localteam
        [player_name] => Jason Puncheon
    )
[24] => Array
    (
        [comm_match_team] => visitorteam
        [player_name] => Eden Hazard
    )

[25] => Array
    (
        [comm_match_team] => visitorteam
        [player_name] => Nemanja Matic
    )
```

And my code

```
 <tbody>
<?php foreach($teams as $team): ?>                             
<tr>
<?php if($team['comm_match_team'] == 'localteam'): ?>
  <td class="home"><?php echo $team['player_name'] ?></td> 
  <?php else: ?>  
  <td class="away"><?php echo $team['player_name'] ?></td>
  <?php endif ?>
</tr>
```

Everytime loop , it add tr tag too , but i want it :

```
<tr>
  <td class="home">Fraizer Campbell</td>   
  <td class="away">Eden Hazard</td>
 </tr>
   <tr>
   <td class="home">Jason Puncheon</td>   
     <td class="away">Nemanja Matic</td>
    </tr>
```

Can anyone give me a solution for this problem ? Thanks

Comment: You are trying to echo out two lines one for home and one for away but you are only echoing out one line of code at the moment. See if you can group it together.

Comment: You're including the <tr> tag inside the `foreach ()` loop. I fear that if you want to reach the result you have sampled here, the array should be split into two. One local and one away, otherwise the `<tr></tr>` tags will be missing, or the list be a single column with both teams.

Comment: I have an array of player of 2 team . Now i want everytime foreach it will make <tr> <td> home player </td> <td> away player </td> </tr> . So if i have 22 player it only have 11 <tr>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php

$c1 = [];
$c2 = [];

foreach($teams as $team) {
    if($team['comm_match_team'] == 'localteam') {
        $c1[] = $team['player_name'];
    }
    else
    {
        $c2[] = $team['player_name'];
    }
}

$count = count($c1);

?>

<?php for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) { ?>
    <tr>
        <td class="home"><?php echo $c1[$i]; ?></td>   
        <td class="away"><?php echo $c2[$i]; ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Your solution doesn't account for the teams being asymmetrical, may I suggest `$count = max(count($c1), count($c2));` with the appropriate measures in the second loop?

Answer (score 0):

```
<tbody>
<tr>
<?php foreach($teams as $team): ?>                             
<?php if($team['comm_match_team'] == 'localteam'): ?>
<td class="home"><?php echo $team['player_name'] ?></td> 
<?php else: ?>  
<td class="away"><?php echo $team['player_name'] ?></td>
<?php endif ?>
//stop foreach here
//then close </tr>
</tr>
```

You should get your `<tr>` out of your foreach loop. Right now everytime you code goes trough the loop it adds an `<tr>` to your table

Comment: This solves the `<tr>` tag issue, but doesn't address the rest of the problem.